# PC not powering off after shutdown

Tags: windows-10, power-supply, shutdown

Just bought a [new PC](https://www.emag.ro/desktop-pc-pentium-g870-dual-core-3-1-ghz-4-gb-ddr3-ssd-120-gb-atx-450w-g870-4gb-ssd120/pd/DJKPHQBBM/) for a fried and I have a "small" problem.

After Win 10 install I turned off the PC, but the monitor is turning off and the PC is not shutting down (cooler and power button led is ON)

Any idea why? How to fix?

Comment: Whats the model of mainboard / bios / version?

Comment: sorry, but I can't check now, only in a few days :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled the following options:

- Wake on LAN
- Wake from Serial Port Ring
- Wake from PCI Device
- Wake Up on Alarm
- disabled "Turn on fast startup" in Windows, Power Options

Now it shuts down correctly